# Set Thread priority to execute same method

Tags: java, multithreading

Here is my conditions: I have two threads, `t1` and `t2`. Both are running. Now, I want to call the method `m1()` by using both threads, but `t2` should execute `m1()` first, and then `t1` will execute next after `t2`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: _I have two threads..._  O.K., Show us the code.  Your description does not completely specifiy what the code does.  The code itself leaves no doubt.

Comment: _t2 should execute m1() first, then t1 will execute..._  Do you literally mean that the threads should execute the method in that order?, or do you merely mean that you don't want them both in the same method at the same time?  The way to make a program do two or more things in a specific order is to do the things in _one_ thread.

Comment: Also, it's a better design choice if, when there's work to be done, it does not matter which thread does the work.  The underlying principle is known as the _single responsibility principle_ (SRP).  It says that any given class/method/module/whatever should be responsible for just one thing.  In an SRP design, you have _task_ objects (E.g., `FoobarTask implements Runnable`) that describe pieces of work to be done, and you have `Thread` objects (typically, hidden inside a _thread pool_) that can _perform_ the tasks, without needing to know what the tasks actually do.

Answer (score 1):

You can set your method as `synchronized` so that `m1()` can't be executed concurrently by multiple threads.